# UIButton width reporting incorrectly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I'm trying to create a circular `UIButton` in Xcode by setting the corner radius equal to half the button width. The problem is, the Storyboard says the width of the button is `200`, but it always reports itself as `46.0` when I access it in the `UIViewController`.

I've tried getting the width using `button.bounds.size.width`, `button.frame.size.width`, `button.layer.frame.size.width`, and `button.bounds.width` and they're all the same.

The crazy thing is I didn't have any trouble after I created a test project and added a big button. The only major difference I could think of was that my project used Auto Layout, but adding a width constraint didn't change anything.

For reference, I'm using Xcode 6.1, Swift, and it's an iPhone-only app targeting iOS 8.

Comment: if you have size classes enabled, make sure that you are adding constraints to the size which you are testing against.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is ending up 46 points wide at runtime, but you want it to be 200 points? 
Make sure your 200 pt width constraint on the button is high priority, dial up its compression resistance and dial down its content hugging (I'm assuming its content would naturally make it the smaller size you are seeing).